# Is there a way to look at position without moving the vertices? (move the verts so it appears like it)

Tags: rotation, three.js, default, angle, direction

I need my object to look in a direction(lookAt), but also reposition verts so that they appear not to move.
I can't seem to find a way to do this.

```
 this.part[this.part.length-1].lookAt(vector);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to figure out how to do it.
I replaced the line with the following

```
 this.part[this.part.length-1].children[0].geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromQuaternion( mesh.quaternion ) );
```

It applies the transformation to the vertices in the geometry as far as I know, based on the orientation of the provided object(mesh).
It solved my problem, but to be more specific to the question; you'd have to store the quaternion before lookat, and then apply this after to move back the vertices. I think.